# yq - make key-value pairs from nested yaml structure

Tags: terminal, yq

Having the following file structure:

```yaml
A1:
    B1:
        description: "B1 field"
    B2:
        any-field: 1
        description: "B2 field"
A2:
    B3:
        any-field: 1
    B4:
        any-field: 1
        description: "B4 field"
```

I would like to get the following result:

```yaml
B1: "B1 field"
B2: "B2 field"
B4: "B4 field"
```

So basically I need to filter out object without desired property (`B3` in this case) and then map each from `.*.* | keys` to `.*.*.description`, but I failed to do it.

`yq` I am using is the newest (4.27.5) from https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go 2-levels deep, you can use the `to_entries` function twice, and then select the key name and the value containing the `.description` field

```bash
yq 'to_entries | .[].value | to_entries | 
      map(select(.value | has("description"))) | .[] | {.key: .value.description}' yaml
```

Comment: I see this is the way it should have been done, despite I did it in very primitive way :)

Comment: Btw. after getting into your solution i see the first part `to_entries | .[].value` is redundant and might be swapped to `.*` to achieve the same result.

Comment: It is upto you to choose the option of your liking. I generally avoid using the recursive select operators like that

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out actually, it was simpler than I expected.
I needed to use string concat here and keyword `key`, which I was not aware of:

```
yq '.*.* | key + ": \"" + .description +"\""' input.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) deliberately omits the document separator `---` in this case (for comparison, at least [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) and [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) do print it), but simply re-mapping the values to move them up one level already brings you here:

```bash
yq '.[] | .[] |= .description' input.yaml
```

```yaml
B1: "B1 field"
B2: "B2 field"
B3: null
B4: "B4 field"
```

So, if this is an intended feature, all that's left is to remove the `null` values:

```bash
yq '.[] | .[] |= .description | del(.[] | select(tag == "!!null"))' input.yaml
```

```yaml
B1: "B1 field"
B2: "B2 field"
B4: "B4 field"
```

Tested with mikefarah/yq 4.27.2